# How to set a relative path in web.config to file in another project within same solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config, relative-path

Okay in my web applications root folder I have two projects (projectA, projectB)
In projectA's web.config I need to reference a file in projectB. I need to use a relative path so not everyone needs to change it each time they pull down my code.

(projectA's web.config)
`<add key="File_Path" value="C:\Users\User1\source\repos\SolutionRoot\projectB\folder1\file.html" />`

Doing something like this doesnt work.
`value="~\projectB\folder1\file.html"`

Can this be done or does it HAVE to be an absolute path everytime.

Comment: Relative paths are supported, but be aware, a web application must be able to access the path.

Comment: Have you tried this:  value="~\..\projectB\folder1\file.html" ?

Comment: Both the projects are web projects?

Comment: I did try ~\..\ but it also did not work. Yes both projects are web projects.